# Sending messages to two services simultaneously usind Service Brokers

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

could I send messages from one service to multiple service using service brokers?

Something like

```
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @dialog_handle
   FROM SERVICE [SERVICE1]
   TO SERVICE 'SERVICE2',**'SERVICE3'**
   ON CONTRACT [MainContract]
```

Looking at the syntax, I do not think we could do this. What's the alternative?

Thanks and Regards

DEE

Comment: Also, if you post some code (like the T-SQL statement), please highlight the lines of code and press the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to properly format the code as code section - this helps a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no publish-subscribe nor multicast built in into Service Broker. To send a message to multiple services you have to explicitly send it to each destination an o a separate dialog.

The typical solution is to send only one message from the application to a service that acts like a distributor. The distributor service receives this message and sends a copy of it to each interested service (Service2, Service3 etc). This way the application doesn't need to know upfront how many services it needs to send the message to, it just sends it to the distributor service.

Comment: Remus,Thanks for your reply . i have a requirement where in i have to wait for all the Target to return (SERVICE1,SERVICE2..). what do you suggest ? should i have a table with all the conversations,messages, initiators,Targets and then update the table when all the messages come from Targets. Thanks for your follow up

Comment: Basically this is like making Async queue's synchronous

Comment: if not Service broker whats the other way to do this, i have to send messages from on DB instance to another and wait for the response.